# Virtualized windows 7 under qemu/kvm hangs

Tags: windows-7, kvm-virtualization, rhel7

I have set up a windows 7 virtual machine using Red Hat 7's standard qemu/kvm.  When I start up the vm, windows boots to the point where it says "Starting Windows" and displays the stylized window. Then nothing further happens.  Anybody know how to fix this?

I should point out that I had no trouble getting this to work on a stand-alone HP Z230.  But when I tried the same setup on an HP DL360 Gen9 server, it hangs as described above.

Comment: Describe your setup: do you use libvirtd? Do you use virt-manager? Show us VM xml config file. Show us qemu-kvm run parameters... I could swear, I've seen it and you use combination of both. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an upstream bug: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/94ef4f337fb6

Roll-back to 2.5.1 and you should see the problem subsist.